# Realtek RTL8111 Network card not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, drivers, ethernet, realtek

I'm trying to install an Ethernet Card into my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop computer. Here is my lspci output (First one is my new ethernet card):

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8053 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

I also installed RTL8111 driver (http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2 which is the first one under Unix(Linux) option).

`lsmod | grep r816` output:

```
r8168 333368  0
```

`lspci -v` output:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 0123
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
I/O ports at ce00 [size=256]
Memory at fe800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at fe7e0000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: r8168
Kernel modules: r8168
```

After driver installation, I arranged the network configuration by these commands:

```
sudo ifconfig eth3 192.168.2.136 netmask 255.255.255.0 up

sudo ifconfig eth3 down && sudo ifconfig eth3 up
```

I know that these are temporary changes, for being permanent I should reorganize etc/network/interfaces file. But from now on I could not succeed on internet connection.

`ifconfig eth3` output:

```
eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:68:05:98  
          inet addr:192.168.2.136  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:44 Base address:0xc000
```

I have not much knowledge about networking but I followed the steps on README.txt file in the driver folder.
Any suggestion about what could be the problem?